# Secure user authentication frameworks, libraries

Tags: php, authentication

I know this question has been asked more then once and more then twice but most answeres i've found here haven't helped me at all.

Since i started to code i've used three selfmade different authentication implementations based on cookies. I've never took much stand against injection or hijacking but this time i am trying to incorporate that in both my user authentiaction and submitting forms.

Since there are thousands of user authentication scripts to choose from i want to ask what frameworks or scripts you would recommend i use? I've tried a few but no one has really done the job? I'm not useing any php framework like Zend, Codeigniter or similar.

I plan on using SSL as well but on some sites my cms will be used on will not have SSL.

Comment: "I'm not useing any php framework". But do you consider the possibility of using one?

Comment: @noisebleed I've of cause thought about it and i might in the future implement a framework. At this time though i want to extend my own.

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Auth which is both framework-agnostic and database-agnostic.

Answer (score 5):

Try this one: http://ulogin.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

If you need an authentication library that ...

- isn't tied to a single framework and
- works with multiple database systems (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, etc.)

... then https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Auth might be for you.

It's modern (PHP 5.6+), secure and convenient.

Comment: Hello. I am newbie here. Setting this up is a total nightmare. Any idea where I can get an example (including codes) that has been implemented with this framework ?

Answer (score 0):

[Symfony2](http://symfony.com/) provides a security component that is available as a **standalone** PHP library.

- Documentation: [Symfony2 - Security](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html)
- Download it from [GitHub](https://github.com/symfony/Security)