# How to use multiple password in php?

Tags: php

I have a password protected webpage with one password. But, I want to use multiple passwords on that webpage... I'm very new to PHP...
So, can anyone give me some advice on how to do this! 
Thanks in Advance!
here is the code I'm using:

```
  <?php
        $password = "anything";
  ?>
```

on that code, I want to use "anything" & also use "mypass" as password same time!
I just use this code for multiplying the pass. but, won't work!

```
  <?php
        $password = "anything" + "mypass";
  ?>
```

& the full code is:

```
    <?php 
    if (isset($_POST["password"]) && ($_POST["password"]=="$password")) {
    ?>

###  anything to hide before password given!

<?php 
}
else
{
if (isset($_POST['password']) || $password == "") {
  print "<p align=\"center\"><font color=\"red\"><b>Wrong Password !!!</b><br>Please enter the correct Password</font></p>";}
  print "<form method=\"post\"><p align=\"center\"><b>Please enter the Password</b><br/><br/>";
  print "<b>Password </b><input class=\"box\" name=\"password\" type=\"password\" maxlength=\"10\"><input class=\"button\" value=\"Download\" type=\"submit\"></p></form>";
}
?>
```

Comment: what do you mean multiple passwords on that webpage?? As it stands, your question is unclear

Comment: best use an existing [login framework/library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127105/secure-user-authentication-frameworks-libraries) or find a php authentication tutorial

Comment: on that code, I want to use "anything" & also use "mypass" as password same time! I just use this code for multiplying the pass. but, won't work!

  <?php
        $password = "anything" + "mypass";
  ?>

Comment: Use an array, then check if the password exists in the array.

Comment: not working! #Qirel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do this

```
$passwordList = ['password','secretPassword','anything'];
if (isset($_POST["password"]) && in_array($_POST["password"], $passwordList)) {
    // do protected stuff here
}
```

**BUT. THERE IS A BIG BUT**

**NEVER EVER STORE PASSOWRDS IN CODE.** Use a database for this.

I recommend you to follow there tutorials from [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/series/php-for-beginners) to get more familiar with PHP

Comment: warning, in_array is not timing-attack safe, this code is vulnerable to timing attacks.

Comment: if you use this method, hackers can literally extract your password from measuring page load times, do not use this method with anything important (not even an important password), hackers can get your password, and access whatever you're trying to secure.

Comment: Thanks a Lot... it's working!!! but, with another improvement here: >> if (isset($_POST['password']) || $password == "") { <<< "$password"  to $passwordList...

Comment: As people mentioned, this type of security check is prone to attacks. Try searching better ways on internet

Comment: @hanshenrik, please provide an alternative solution

Answer (score 2):

use an array of passwords. btw

`==` and `===` is vulnerable to [timing attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack), use `hash_equals` instead, but even hash_equals is vulnerable to timing attacks [if the length of the 2 inputs is not equal](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/f9822b143e5726d5916223cc65842271b2b6ab2d/ext/hash/hash.c#L869), so hash the passwords before comparing them, to pad the length. something like

```
$authed=false;
if (isset($_POST["password"])){
    $passwords=array('pass1','pass2','pass3');
    $u=hash('md5',(string)$_POST["password"],true); // using a weak (and fast) CS hash is not a problem, because we're only using it to pad the length so we're not vulnerable to a timing attack. 
    foreach($passwords as $pass){
        if(hash_equals($u,hash('md5',$pass,true))){
            $authed=true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
// here $authed is true if a correct password was supplied
```

Answer (score 1):

once try:

```
$password = "anything";
$password = $password . "mypass";
//anythingmypass

if (isset($_POST["password"]) && $_POST["password"] != $password) {

print '<p align="center"><font color="red"><b>Wrong Password !!!</b><br>Please enter the correct Password</font></p>';
} else if (isset($_POST['password']) && $_POST['password']==$password) {
echo "password correct";
}
print '<form method="post"><p align="center"><b>Please enter the Password</b><br/><br/>';
print '<b>Password </b><input class="box" name="password" type="password" maxlength="' . strlen($password).'"><input class="button" value="Download" type="submit"></p></form>';
```

Comment: md5() is way too weak. There are PHP functions for dealing with passwords